# Java Debugger says, that i have problem with java version

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-12

After build attempt, java debugger extension pack returns:

[image]

My Java environment:

[image]

My settings:

[image]

If i press Proceed, application programm works correctly.
There some few java versions, but i'm already added PATH and JAVA_HOME.

[image]

How can i disable that problems from Java Debugger Extension in VSCode?

Comment: The problem may be due to the Java Debugger Extension not supporting this version of Java. Try using it with Java 8. Also, check any settings in VS Code that might be setting Java source and target versions to 1.6 or below (I'm not familiar with VS Code so don't know where to find them).

Comment: Based on some compilation errors (e.g.: `'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7`), it looks like you have the source level for your build set to an invalid value (perhaps 5 instead of 12?), so review the build settings for your project.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the extension generated file `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` like :

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```